# Need help identifying right XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, html-table, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape all of the table from this website : https://qmjhldraft.rinknet.com/results.htm?year=2018

When the XPath is a simple td (like the names for example), I can scrape the table with the simple xpath being something like this :

```
players = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@rnid]/td[4]')
```

And I can scrape the players name using this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://qmjhldraft.rinknet.com/results.htm?year=2018')

try:
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@rnid]/td[1]"))
    )
finally:
    players = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@rnid]/td[4]')
    
for player in players[:5]:
    pl = player.text
    print(pl)
```

But when I get to the "Height" section, I can't find the write XPath. I guess this has to do with the td having a class, "ht-itemVisibility1", changing the way to scrape it, I've tried a few different ways to scrape it, like :

```
('//tr/td[@class="ht-itemVisibility1"][1]')
('//tr/td[@class="ht-itemVisibility1"][5]')
('//tr[@rnid]/td[5]')
```

to no avail. Can someone enlighten me on the way to capature this XPath with td class? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://qmjhldraft.rinknet.com/results.htm?year=2018')

try:
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@rnid]/td[1]"))
    )
finally:
    players = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@rnid]/td[4]')
    
for player in players[:5]:
    pl = player.text
    print(pl)

players_height = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[@class="ht-itemVisibility1"][1]')

for player in players_height[:5]:
    pl = player.text
    print(pl)

players_last_team = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[@class="ht-itemVisibility1"][5]')

for player in players_last_team[:5]:
    pl = player.text
    print(pl)
```

don't know why it wasn't working for you but it's working fine with me.

Results:
[image]

Comment: thanks again, will try this tonight